# Firebase database UI kept open causing quota issue

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-console

It looks like keeping open the Firebase database UI (their UI) is causing massive quota issue.

I don't have many users in the app today (barely less than 5). I opened the UI and navigated to usage page and immediately the spike started. It took a while to stop.

Has anyone experienced this issue if not did I get DDoS'd ??? If I did get DDoS'd how can I prevent such attacks when there is limited control over the db?

Comment: If the traffic is caused by you opening the Firestore console, it's not a DDoS since it's only you. If you are getting DDoS'd, it's unlikely to be caused by your opening of the Firestore console. Either way: it's unlikely anyone here can do much about this. I recommend you [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is better handled by Firebase support.